# Flutter PUSH Notification icon not showing

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, launcher-icon

**I tried to add flutter app icon by using a package flutter_launcher_icon app icon is correct but icons shows in push notification show as a white box
Notification Icon Shows as a white box**

## [image]

[image]

**Resource File**
[image]

**I added icons by using a package [[flutter_launcher_icons]](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)**
[image: pubspec.yaml file]

**Expected Output**
[image]

Comment: I think flutter_launcher_icon is not for the notification but for the application icon. But I want to know what package so you use for the notification ?

Answer (score 0):

same error have happened to me so i have used icon as xml file in android

[image]

we have to add that file name here

```
 void showNotification(int orderCount) async {
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('fav_icon');
    var initializeSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    var res = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializeSettings) ?? false;
    Log.d("Notification manager initialized $res");
    if (res) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          1,
          "Order",
          "You have new notifications",
          NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails('NOTIFICATION', 'New order notifications',
                  channelDescription: 'Shows notifications when new orders are available',
                  importance: Importance.max,
                  priority: Priority.high,
                  playSound: true,
                  category: AndroidNotificationCategory.event,
                  color: MyColor.kSecondary)));
    }
  }
```